# Magento 2 grid uiComponent: include a table alias in a column filter

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I created a grid using an uiComponent XML file, and for the dataProvider, I provided a collection that is using JOINs with some additional tables.

Because of that, I'm getting the following error while trying to filter the grid by the email field:

```
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous
```

which is correct. The email field is present both in the main table and in one of the joined tables.

So my question is: how can I make the email column filter use the `main_table.email` instead of just `email` in the query? I tried to search for solutions in core uiComponents, but none of them seem to have such ambiguous columns (along with a solution for that).

My column definition looks like this:

```
<column name="email">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

I also tried putting this code in the `<filters>` tag to check if it helps:

```
<filterInput name="email">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">main_table.email</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</filterInput>
```

But it turns out it doesn't. What should I do to achieve the desired effect, apart from changing the collection query itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conflicts in where clause with ambiguous column names](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262/conflicts-in-where-clause-with-ambiguous-column-names)

Comment: Did you find how ? ...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can force using table alias in condition with `addFilterToMap()` method. Apply it in the `_initSelect()` method of your Collection class:

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    $this->addFilterToMap('email', 'main_table.email');

    parent::_initSelect();
}
```

I found this answer here [Conflicts in where clause with ambiguous column names](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262/conflicts-in-where-clause-with-ambiguous-column-names)

Comment: thanks for your above code, i was stuck for this and it really saved my time.

Comment: Perfect answer!!! +1 made my day :)